# jQuery object and the window object

Tags: jquery

I am playing around with the guts of jQuery just to get a feel for how it works.  I understand it for the most part, but I am curious about something.

In jQuery, we have this to actually create the jQuery object (on line `60`):

```
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
},
```

The `init` method is long, so I will spare you the copy and paste (check the source if you want to see it, it's on line `123`).  This method is made available through `jQuery.prototype`.  Essentially, it looks at the arguments and makes some decisions about element selection.

Further down the script (on line `19174`) we have this:

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

Which is interesting, because commenting out this line still makes `$` available in the global object.

Why is this needed?  It seems as though the `jQuery` function which calls the `init` method creates the global of `$` either way.  I tested this on Chrome, Firefox and Safari and they can all live without the `Expose jQuery to the global object` line.

Is this for older browsers and for backwards compatibility??

Comment: Are you sure? Because, I commented the line and it throws me an error when I alert `$`. http://jsfiddle.net/RBG7P/

Comment: Have you tried in browsers locally??

Comment: I chose no library and jsfiddle, How should I test locally?

Comment: @SethenMaleno Why would it make any difference, other than that you run the risk of using a cached version?

Comment: I downloaded the HTML5 boilerplate and commented out the line in an uncompressed source.

Comment: @Juhana For the sake of understanding how the tools I use actually work.

Comment: Are you sure the boilerplate isn't pointing at a minified version...?

Comment: I'm sure.  I took out the `window.$ ||` line.  Pointing to a local uncompressed copy.

Comment: And if you add something like an alert or write something to the console in jQuery version you modified, you see that message?

Comment: I have that line commented out and I have selected an element with an `id` of `hello` and it's selecting the element just fine.

Comment: Also, it's not enough to just take out the `window.$` line. You have to remove all lines that would load the script from CDNs, or scripts that might redefine `$`.

Comment: @Juhana The question is why is that line there in the first place.  I think you're missing the point.

Comment: Well, @Vega's jsfiddle proves that the line is there to expose the `$` symbol as a global object. Unless *you* can prove that it doesn't do that, for example by uploading the version where you have commented out the line and `$` is still available, I'm just going to have to go with your experiment being flawed.

Comment: @Juhana Then I shall take my 4 upvotes with me.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery library is defined in the closure and that line is what really expose the library to the global scope.

```
alert($)
```

I tried commenting that line in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RBG7P/1/ and it throws me an exception. When un-commented, it worked.

Are you sure you are doing it the right way?

Comment: Yes.  Locally on my machine, `$` is still defined even if I comment out that line.

Comment: Stack Overflow validation enforcing me to post code before I could submit this answer and so the `alert($)`.

Comment: @SethenMaleno Define locally? What exactly are you trying out locally. Is it possible that you are defining it somewhere else.

Comment: Meaning, not sourced via the Google CDN.  The jQuery source is local on my machine.

Comment: @SethenMaleno In the fiddle, I copied the jQuery source inside the fiddle and there is no link/reference to any external resources. It should be the same as local.

Comment: Not getting the same results locally.